# Not seeing text alignment option in Image block

Tags: images, block-editor

I am editing some posts on my wordpress blog and want to insert some text to the right of image. But as seem in screenshot below, there is no such option in Gutenberg image block editor.

Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this.

Just want to add that, my posts have been imported form medium.com and i am new to wordpress, so may be i am missing something basic. But due to above issue, i am not able to proceed at all. 
Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Image block]

Answer (score 1):

Using the Align options you found (Align left, Align center, Align right) is often the easiest way to allow text to flow around your images in your WordPress posts.

1. Add the Image
2. Select Align right in Image options
3. Add some text (puts Image in Paragraph block)
4. Adjust the width of the Image block
   so the text flows around

[image: Add image in Paragraph block]

[image: Adjust the width of the Image block]

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options:

You could use the [media and text block](https://wordpress.org/support/article/media-text-block/) which is designed for inserting text next to an image.

Or you could use the columns block, select a layout that only has 2 columns and then on the left column you can insert image and in the right column, insert text.